# Classifier using pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I'm writing a demo code to predict a 2-class classification for a dataset of 10-D inputs. Below, function  `_data` generates the data:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

def _data(dimension, num_examples):
    # Create a simulated 10-dimensional training dataset consisting of 1000 labeled
    # examples, of which 800 are labeled correctly and 200 are mislabeled.
    num_mislabeled_examples = 20
    # We will constrain the recall to be at least 90%.
    recall_lower_bound = 0.9

    # Create random "ground truth" parameters for a linear model.
    ground_truth_weights = np.random.normal(size=dimension) / math.sqrt(dimension)
    ground_truth_threshold = 0

    # Generate a random set of features for each example.
    features = np.random.normal(size=(num_examples, dimension)).astype(
        np.float32) / math.sqrt(dimension)
    # Compute the labels from these features given the ground truth linear model.
    labels = (np.matmul(features, ground_truth_weights) >
              ground_truth_threshold).astype(np.float32)
    # Add noise by randomly flipping num_mislabeled_examples labels.
    mislabeled_indices = np.random.choice(
        num_examples, num_mislabeled_examples, replace=False)
    labels[mislabeled_indices] = 1 - labels[mislabeled_indices]

    return torch.tensor(labels), torch.tensor(features)
```

The code below shows my attempt, where `predictor` is the model and the loss function is chosen to be Hinge loss.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

dim = 10
N = 100
target, features = _data(dim, N)

class predictor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(predictor, self).__init__()
        self.f_1 = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, features):
        return self.f_1(features)

model = predictor()

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-2)
loss = torch.nn.HingeEmbeddingLoss(margin=1.0, size_average=None, reduce=None, reduction='mean')

running_loss = 0
for _ in range(1000):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(features)
    objective = loss(output, target)
    objective.backward()
    running_loss += objective.item()
    optimizer.step()

    print(running_loss)
```

**My questions:**

1. I see my loss increase from zero to 20 and then dives deep into negative realm. I was wondering if my implementation is correct.
2. I was trying to implement my predictor without using `nn.Linear` by defining the computations myself as:

```
class predictor(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(predictor, self).__init__()
        self.weights = torch.zeros(dim, dim, requires_grad=True)
        self.threshold = torch.zeros(1, 1, requires_grad=True)

    def forward(self, features):
        return torch.matmul(self.weights, features) - self.threshold
```

but in the optimization process,

```
model = predictor()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
```

I get the following error:

> ValueError: optimizer got an empty parameter list

I would appreciate direction or comments on how to fix these issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Choose lr of optimizer something very small. It might be because of exploding gradient.
2. In self.weight use nn.Parameter() then pass your torch.zeros() to make it a model parameter.

Comment: Thanks, could you alter my `class predictor(nn.Module)` with `nn.Parameter()` so I can understand?

Comment: Refer to this article. You will find detailed explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51027227/11961138

Comment: It seems that in order for this predictor to work, I would have to know the batch size in advance. In other words, when doing 

```torch.matmul(self.weights, features) - self.threshold```

I need the batch size to set the dimensionality of `self.weights` in advance. However, when using `nn.Linear(10, 1)` I don't have to deal with the batch size anymore. Is this true or should I change something?

Comment: Nvm, I just set the dimensions wrong. Thank you!